# Separating Tags in a single MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a data dump of stack overflow, and in a post, there is a column (type:String) for tags which takes this form:

```
"<apache><tomcat><java><httpd><virtualhost>"
```

How would I go about breaking these apart using SQL into separate rows?

So that I have a resulting table like this:

```
ID    |          Tag
--------------------
1     |       apache
2     |       tomcat
3     |         java
4     |        httpd
5     |  virtualhost
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break this apart with logic like this:

```
select replace(replace(substring(substring_index(col, '><', n), '><', -1), '<', ''), '>', '')
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 select 4 union all select 5
     ) n join
     table t
     on length(col) - replace(length(replace(col, '>' '') <= n.n
```

The logic in the `select` is basically extracting the nth item from the list.  It also removes the `<` and `>` from the values.

The logic in the join is to get the number for the nth element.

Answer (score 0):

Does your dump include a full list of Stack Overflow tags? If so, then I would put them into a separate table and do the following:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS ID, t1.Tag
  FROM tag_table t1 INNER JOIN post_table p1
 WHERE p1.tags LIKE CONCAT('%<', t1.tag, '>%')
   AND p1.PostID = <whatever the post ID is>;
```

Comment: No, it does not include a tags table.